# How to pass input value to JavaScript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, function

I have this code and want to pass the input to my `GoLargeSearch` function when I click the image.

```
<div id="s4-searcharea-large">
    <input accessKey="S" onkeydown="CoreInvoke('LargeSearchKeyDownGoSearch', event)" id="txtLargeSearchTerm" runat="server" class="ms-sharepointsearchtext" title="Enter search words" value="" maxLength="255" size="25" type="text" name="SearchString" /> 
    <div class="ms-searchimage">
        <span style="position: relative; width: 27px; display: inline-block; height: 27px; overflow: hidden" class="s4-clust">
            <a style="width: 27px; display: inline-block; height: 27px" id="onetIDGoSearchLarge" title="Search" onclick="GoLargeSearch(document.getElementById('txtLargeSearchTerm'))" href="javascript:">
                <img style="border-bottom: 0px; position: absolute; border-left: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px;" alt="Search" src="/_layouts/GP_Custom/images/largesearch.png" />
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the value of the input to pass it to `GoLargeSearch`? 
This doesn't seem to work:

```
onclick="GoLargeSearch(document.getElementById('txtLargeSearchTerm'))"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the part where you get the value of that element:

```
onclick="GoLargeSearch(document.getElementById('txtLargeSearchTerm').value)"
```

Comment: What happens if you just alert the value of that element? `alert(document.getElementById('txtLargeSearchTerm').value)`

Comment: onclick=alert(document.getElementById('txtLargeSearchTerm').value) also gives me an object required error at runtime

Comment: This gives me a 'System' is undefined error: 

onclick="$get(<%=txtLargeSearchTerm %>)"

Comment: Something somewhere else is conflicting with this. I can't say where as I obviously don't know about your code to figure it out. But the answer above will work once you can sort out what is causing this new issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
function GoLargeSearch (obj) { alert(obj.value); }
```

But it's very ugly code =/
Aren't  you able to use JQuery?

Comment: No I'm getting System is undefined error. . . . Values are being passed to my function just fine. For example if I did : onclick=GoLargeSearch("Hello") then Hello would be passed to my function. What i'm having trouble with is getting the value from my textbox input

Comment: Also i'm using javascript, HTML, visual studio 2010. And this is for a custom webpart in Sharepoint.